# How to invert every other tiled background image?

Tags: javascript, css

I know it is possible to invert an image just using CSS, but what about the tiling effect of background images? I have an image that fills the screen horizontally, but is tiled vertically. Can I flip every other image vertically?

Comment: What if you created an image that was the initial image + an invert image, then used that as your background image?

Comment: That would work, but I'd like to keep the image as small as possible--if possible.

Answer (score 1):

maybe with a pseudo transform and mix-blend-mode : (not for ie ! ):

black linear-gradients are used to blend/hide image, it needs to be size twice the sice of image : here i used a 200px tall image, so gradient needs to be 400px where half is black and the other transparent.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
html {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 50%, black 50%), url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/7);
  background-size: 400px 400px, auto;
}
html:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 50%, black 50%) bottom right, url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200/nature/7) bottom right;
  background-size: 400px 400px, auto;
  transform: scale(-1);
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

body {
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
  display:flex;
  }
h1 {margin:auto;color:white;text-shadow:0 0 2px black;}
```

```html
<h1> Mix-blend-mode test</h1>
```

note, wait untill background image are loaded before any opinion, lorempixel.com is sometimes slow)

---

with a full width image :

*Gradient has to be turned into a translucide black & transparent png of same width and double height of image .*

example:

```css
html, body {
  height:100%;
  margin: 0;
}
html {
  background:url(data:image/png;base64,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) top left, url(http://lorempixel.com/868/200/abstract/1) top left;
  background-size:100% auto, 100% auto;
}
html:before {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
  background:url(data:image/png;base64,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) bottom right, url(http://lorempixel.com/868/200/abstract/1) bottom right;
  background-size:100% auto, 100% auto;
  transform:scale(1,-1);
  mix-blend-mode:difference;
}
body {
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
  display:flex;
  font-size:2vw
  }
h1 {margin:auto;color:#F9F3EE;text-shadow:0 0 2px #D999A3;}
```

```html
<h1>Test via mix-blend-mode if your browser supports it !</h1>
```

Comment: You've gone the wrong way btw ;) - he needs it to be tiled vertically, not horizontally - having said that, nice answer!

Comment: @CalvT oh yes, just fixed reverting gradient direction :)

Comment: @GCyrillus This is great! The only problem with it is that I'm using one long thin image horizontally with width 100%, not repeating the image in both directions. Is this still possible with a single axis? I'm getting weird repeating black spaces in the middle of the page.

Comment: @user3233346 it is of course possible, as commented, resize the linear-gradient to the height of the image , any image does :) , what are the dimension of your image ?, could it be seen ?

Comment: @GCyrillus it's 868x[whatever], but I use 100% for width so it scales with the screen size. The issue seems to be though I use   background-size: 100% 200%, auto; the black areas are determining the 50% size of the unadjusted image rather than 50% screen size.

Comment: @user3233346 in this case, instead gradient you may use a real image (a translucide png) twice as tall of your image and same width: (quick made example) http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/vKNLJJ

Comment: @GCyrillus I might just suck it up and reflect the image, adding another image twice as large as the one I have--part of which is transparent--doesn't sound like what I'm looking for at all.

Comment: @user3233346  so CSS at this point cannot do anything for you, jthe simple thing to do is to create that image before upload, or on server side, PhP has librarry to treat/create image that can copy and reflect that image underneath itself.. http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Answer (score 0):

From my experience thus far, I don't think that flipping only part of the `background-image` is possible; at least with CSS3.

However, you can achieve your desired result with a couple of ways (there may be more):

• You can create a top `div` having having the `height` of your background image and `width: 100%` to have its background normal and then create another `div` with `width: 100%` again and `height` the remainder of the screen where you put your tiling background inverse.

Check out the result in the snippet.

```css
#div1 {
  height: 100px;
  background: url("http://cdn.backyardchickens.com/e/ed/200x400px-LL-ed0a9036_image.jpeg");
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
#div2 {
  height: 500px;
  background: url(http://cdn.backyardchickens.com/e/ed/200x400px-LL-ed0a9036_image.jpeg);
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  /*Invert*/
  -moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
  -o-transform: scaleY(-1);
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

• Alternatively, you can create an image with the same dimensions as your screen, set the effects you want and then use that image as a `background-image`.

Comment: I think you're missing the fact that the OP said - "every other image" suggesting that the background image isn't very tall, so it will be tiled multiple times.

Comment: The OP can create a div big enough to for the background to fit once and then another div where he reverses the multiple tiles it will have.

Comment: What if his image is only 50px tall? For a Full HD screen (1080px) he would have to create a total of 22 divs...

Comment: The div are TWO! One at the height of the image (say 50px) to fill it with the image being normal and another div with `height: calc(100% - 50px)` where the OP will put the background image flipped and make it repeat on the y axis.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from my comment, I would think the simplest, and maybe only way to do what you want is to create a new image. So say you start with this image:

[image]

By flipping the image and adding it to the bottom, you get this:

[image]

So then you can simply replace your current url in your CSS and get this:

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxF8o.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-size:cover;
  }
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want this. They want the inverted image only to be repeated on the y axis; not both.

Comment: @AngelPolitis I see! So where in my code does the background image repeat on the x axis? I think you need to have a look at my code again ;) - note `background-size: cover` meaning the image will stretch from left to right, then `background-repeat: repeat-y;` meaning it will tile down.....

Comment: Come man, where did I talk about the x axis. Whatever... What said is that the OP wants only inverted image to be tiled. In your example both get repeated.

Comment: @AngelPolitis What does "every other" image mean then? In proper english, the old english known as british english, it means that every second image should be tiled, so normal, tiled, normal, tiled, normal, etc

Comment: @AngelPolitis I suppose it's down to the OPs grasp of the english language then.... Here's an example from another site on stackexchange on what it really means [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79010/meaning-of-every-other-day-week#) and also [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12690/what-is-the-meaning-of-every-other-time)

Comment: Check out my answer. The OP may not be an english-speaking person and you are just becoming offensive.

Comment: @AngelPolitis I apologize if you think I was being offensive, it wasn't my intention, I was simply pointing out facts.

Comment: It's okay. I know what was asked was not stated clearly and that we can only assume what they OP wants for the time being. I would have edited the question if I knew exactly what that is they want :P

Comment: "Every other image" is intended to imply "normal, inverted, normal, inverted." Sorry about that.